# Multiple asp.net requests calling same sql server 2005 stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Before I start, I couldn't find any other resources to answer my question, closest is:
[Calling a stored procedure simultaniously  from multiple threads in asp.net and sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690889/calling-a-stored-procedure-simultaniously-from-multiple-threads-in-asp-net-and)
but it fails to answer my specific issue/concern.

Basically, I have a massive .net web app that handles millions of requests a day.

**Assume:**

- All of sprocs concerned are simple get sprocs(ex, SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [SOMEWHERE] INNER JOIN [SOMETHING ELSE] etc....)
- All data never changes(it does change from time to time, for the sake of my scenario, assume it doesn't)
- The cache is initially empty for whatever reason.

**The method in question:**
I check for the existence of the object in the application cache.  If it exists, I simply return it.  If the object is not in cache, a sproc call is made to the database to look up this data. Once the sproc returns, this data is added to cache and then returned.

Under heavy load I have a bit of a performance issue that I'd like to clear up.

**Here's my scenario:**

1. User A comes into this method.
2. Data is not in cache, sproc gets called.
3. User B comes into this method(while sproc is still running).
4. Data is not in cache, sproc gets called.
5. Rinse and repeat over and over.

Under heavy load, these can generate quite a lot of concurrent and redundant active spids.  I'm trying to figure out the best way around this.  Obviously I could drop in an sp_getAppLock but the requests would still end up 1) dropping into the sproc and 2) have to fire the exact same query.  I could lock on an object that is specific to that exact query and have that wrapped around the cache check.  But if I do that, I'm potentially opening the door for some massive thread contention and deadlocking.

I have to assume that someone has dealt with this very scenario before and I'm hopeful there is an appropriate solution.  Right now the best solution I can come up with is application locking, but I'd really like to know if anyone has any better options. Perhaps a combination of things, say sql app locks and messaging(traditional or non traditional) where after the lock succeeds, any that were just released try to pull down the result-set(from where?) as opposed to re-executing the entire rest of the sproc.

**EDIT:**
So follow this.... If I lock or "wait" either the caching or the sproc call, under heavy load it's possible that if an element is not cached and the method(or sproc) that generates the to-be-cached object could end up taking longer than expected.  While that is spinning away, threads are going to have to wait.  By waiting, the only way(at least that I know) is to lock or spin.
Isn't it then possible to have thread pool exhaustion or lock up all available requests and force the requests to be queued? This is my fear and the thing that drove me to look into moving the layer away from the application and into the database.  The last time we attempted to lock around the caching, we suffered from severe CPU spikes on our web box because the threads sat in a lock state for so long.  Though I believe at the time we did not use Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit(or just lock(){}).  Either way, does anyone have any details or experience in this area?  I know it's typically bad form to lock on long running processes for this very reason.  I would suffer loading duplicate content into cache if I could avoid preventing user requests from dropping into the request queue because I'm all out of threads or all active requests are locked.

Or, maybe it's just late and I'm over thinking this.  I had started my day with an almost brilliant, "ah-ha" moment.  But now I just keep second guessing myself.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET problem, not T-SQL. How does the DB server know why you call it?

Comment: This is a multithreading / resource contention problem. It is not C#, not asp.net, and not sql.

Comment: Indeed it is. Though it is a multithreading/resource contention problem that just happens to deal with all of those elements.  There in is the reason I used those tags.

Comment: You did say assume the data does not change. If the data does not change why not just run the sp's when the application starts and expose the results as static values?

Comment: If the data does not change then use with (nolock) for speed and reducing locks.  Please post you code where you check the existance and call the sp.

Answer (score 2):

Your cache is most likely protected by a lock, so you are already serializing the threads.

Your suggested solution is the best: have a lock around the query.  Once the cache is populated the performance difference will be negligible, and you'll avoid multiple (and expensive) database queries.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I has this problem, when cache was flushes and slow queries take my DB down.

Here some solution for this heavy problem is using Locking, ignore the Hebrew explain and look in the code:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/moshel/archive/2009/07/11/cache.aspx

Comment: Any recommendations on whether or not I should be locking on strings as this example shows? Not sure if I should worry about interning, but say that I have multiple instances of this application running.  Doesn't interning suggest that I could potentially be locking then across domains? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: As I am using Cache() (or Memcache) I need to use thses strings and know what I do.
You can use locking with objects, or use `Monitor.TryEnter()` to get/set an timeout for locking.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into cache optimization if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running through a cachemanager anyway, can it not be made smart enough to know that the proc has already been called and it should wait for it to complete?

```
GetData() {
  if (cached) return cache;
  if (caching) {
    // wait for it to finish
    return cache;
  }
  caching=true;
  cache = CallProc();
  cached = true;
  caching = false;
}
```

Comment: We've actually tried this before, but slow running sprocs ended up causing severe request locking/queuing.  I suppose we could attempt it again. I'm sure I could write something at this level to just ignore those ones or do something a bit more intelligent.  Either way, I think this is the direction I'll have to follow, thanks much.